# Improve sprite drawing performance

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I have this function to draw a sprite object (which is just an object with an array of pixel values):

```
this.draw = (ctx, x, y, scale) => {
    let i = 0;
    let startIndex, red, green, blue, alpha, currentX, currentY;
    while(i < this.size.width * this.size.height){
        startIndex = i * 4;
        red = this.pixArray[startIndex];
        green = this.pixArray[startIndex + 1];
        blue = this.pixArray[startIndex + 2];
        alpha = this.pixArray[startIndex + 3];
        // Draw, but not if the pixel is invisible
        if(alpha != 0){
            ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${red}, " + ${green} + ", " + ${blue} + ", " + ${alpha / 255.0} + ")`;
            currentX = i % this.size.width;
            currentY = (i - currentX) / this.size.width;
            ctx.fillRect(Math.round(x + (currentX * scale)), Math.round(y + (currentY * scale)),
            Math.round(scale), Math.round(scale));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

The only thing missing from this is `pixArray`, which is an Uint8Array of pixel values.

However, performance is fairly abysmal. I have found that some of the performance is lost to the canvas changing state (`ctx.fillStyle`), but it is necessary that I modify this each iteration. Even if the fillStyle remains unchanged, the performance is still unacceptable. I realize I have the option or pre-rendering, but I wish to avoid this.

Comment: WebGL is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) to blit your array directly to a temporary canvas and then draw that to the destination canvas with the appropriate scale in a single operation:

```
const { width, height } = this.size;
const tCan = document.createElement('canvas');

// block scope to clean up temporary variables
{
  const tCtx = tCan.getContext('2d');
  const imgData = tCtx.createImageData(width, height);

  tCan.width = width;
  tCan.height = height;
  imgData.data.set(this.pixArray);
  tCtx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}

this.draw = (ctx, x, y, scale) => {
  ctx.drawImage(tCan, x, y, Math.round(width * scale), Math.round(height * scale));
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not scale without anti-aliasing, which is required for sprite-style images (32 pixels by 32 pixels, to be exact)

Comment: Do it even only once, at initialization and keep the image on an offscreen canvas, `draw` would then just be drawImage(offscrenCanvas... @AlgoRythm for antialiased drawing, set your destination context's `imageSmoothingEnabled` to false.